# How to transfer data from one list to another in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a small to-to list, I'm stuck in views.py, there are to-do
tasks, in-progress tasks and done tasks, I want to move a task from the
to-do task list to the in-progress task list, I can't figure out how to
delete the data in the to-to task and make new data same as to-do task
in the in-progress task at the same time. It would be great if anyone
can help, I'm totally new to Django. Thanks.

'''

```
models.py


class Todo(models.Model):

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:60] + "..."

class Progress(models.Model):  
    
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    name = models.ForeignKey(Todo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

'''

Comment: You want to indicate that a Todo has a certain status associated with it (in progress). You would not handle that by creating another duplicate model of Todo. The simplest solution is to simply put another field on your Todo model that indicates the status.

Comment: @aris I'm not sure how to do it, could u explain more, plz?

Comment: I think I know what u mean now@aris Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest only having one class, with an extra row for whether they are in progress or not. This will save you from creating and deleting django and DB objects over and over, when through their lifecycle they are the same information. You can achieve this in a few ways: a float field to track percentage of completeness, or just a boolean. For simplicity of example, I'll use a boolean.

```
`class Todo(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    in_progress = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name`
```

Then in your views you can query for those tasks that are or are not in progress. As mentioned above you could also use a float field and then do a search for anything greater that 0.

Comment: It's a great idea and a great direction for me to find out the answer, thanks buddy, ill accept ur answer if there is no other answers.

Comment: I have concerns in displaying these data in HTML because after I changing the status, I don't want it to be in the same position, I have another position to show in-progress tasks, so I'm not sure changing status can achieve that?

Comment: You can declare them as different variables in the view and pass them as different elements. For example:

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Todo

def todo_with_progress(request):
        not_started = Todo.objects.filter(in_progress=False)
        started = Todo.objects.filter(in_progress=True)
        context = {'not_started': not_started, 'started': started,}
    return render(request, 'someHTMLTemplate.html', context)

You should then be able to access them by their jinja template hooks on your html document and manipulate them separately.

Comment: Also, sorry that didn't render as code on my comment. If you drop it in you idea and manipulate it into syntactical python, it will make sense.